# What does Ubuntu "consists" of? How do I find out?

Tags: system

A typical Ubuntu (or any Linux) installation is not just a kernel, it's a bunch of things- a file system, a windows manager, a set of tools and other frameworks. I would like to know what Ubuntu (or any other Linux distro for that matter) is assembled from. Where do I find this information (or alternatively- perhaps someone here could produce the list themselves)?

Comment: Although not Ubuntu specific, reading the documentation from [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) is useful in general for learning about how an installation could be built from the ground up.

Comment: Ubuntu Packages Search: http://packages.ubuntu.com lets you browse the available packages by category.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest method - install Ubuntu, open up the Terminal, and `dpkg --get-selections > /tmp/packagelist.txt`.  Peruse `/tmp/packagelist.txt` at your leisure.  If you wonder what any of those things are, `apt-cache show packagename`.  If that's not enough information, start Googlin'.